# Get HTTP status for a list of URLs using Postman

Tags: web-crawler, postman

I need to get HTTP status codes for a specific list of URLs. Additionally, when postman encounters a URL with a redirect (3XX status code), i need it to show where the original URL was redirected. I know there are a ton of programs that can do this with ease (screaming frog, deepcrawl, etc.) but i also need to leverage another feature of Postman which is to pass a header value along with the request. I'm honestly surprised that none of the 'off-the'shelf' web crawlers are capable of this...

Anyway, I stumbled across this blog post from Postman and it seems like its 50% of what i need but I have zero clue on how to modify the test script to operate from a static list instead of crawling webpages to build a a dynamic list.

http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/06/23/check-for-broken-links-on-your-website-using-a-postman-collection/

Any help would be seriously appreciated!! Also open to other solutions outside of Postman so long as it can pass header values with each request.